# How to get the base directory for making AJAX requests to a server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ajax

I'm trying to make a small Node.js Project. The client side of the project will be making many AJAX requests with the server. I'm trying to make code that will work with all web pages, but I discovered that the path is relative to the location of the page. How do I make the path start at the base directory of my website?

```
//I've tried doing this
var path = require(path);
var myPath = path.join(__dirname, '../');
```

/*The error was that I couldn't user require in client side javascript  like you can do in Node.js*/

The error was: require is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget about the `path` module:

- You aren't dealing with **directory** paths
- It isn't available in a web browser

Use a *relative* URL with an **absolute** path.

```
const myPath = "/foo/bar"
```

Note also that you can't construct a URL that will resolve to somewhere *above* the webroot. The webroot is the very top.

Comment: Ok, but if I'm on the page localhost:3000/subpage and I use "/foo/bar", then it will use "localhost:3000/subpage/foo/bar", which I don't want it to do. I want it go to "localhost:3000/foo/bar". Can you please explain how to do that?

Comment: @programmerRaj — You're wrong. That will do what you want, not what you say it will do.

Comment: Ok I will try out what you said and see if it works.